# How to make a directory and put all the files generated in to that directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which generates multiple files after running the script. So **i need all this files that is generated to be stored in to the directory created. and also if i run the script i need the the script to check if that directory already exist or not.**

1. **if exist remove the previous contents in the directory and then only new contents should be stored in the directory.**

eg: when i run script, Folder `new` is first created and then files `demo1.txt` and `demo2.txt` which gets generated when i run the script is stored in to that directory. And if i run the script again i need all the first files created in that directory to be cleared.

This is my current attempt:

```
 import os
        if not os.path.exists("home/Documents/new"):
            os.makedirs("home/Documents/new")

            f = open("demo1.txt", "w")
            f.write("welcome to python")
            f.close()

            f = open("demo2.txt", "w")
            f.write("new world")
            f.close()
```

but this will only create the directory. I'm not able to put the files to the directory

Comment: `open` is being provided the path to the file you wish to write to. You are passing `demo1.txt` but you want to write it in `home/Documents/new/demo1.txt`, so you should pass that path to `open`. You could try making a variable `output_directory = r'home/Documents/new'` and build the file paths from it with something like `demo1_path = os.join(output_directory, 'demo1.txt')`

Comment: Can you provide an imaginary dictionary so we can see exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) if the new directory doesn't exist, you need to change to it prior to create the files. b) if the new directory was created in a previous run, your files are never created in the current run (watch out for indentation!). Modifying a bit your script, this will always create the files in the new directory, whether it was already created in previous runs or not:

```
import os

newdir = "home/Documents/new"

if not os.path.exists(newdir):
    os.makedirs(newdir)

olddir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(newdir)  # change execution to newdir                                                                                                                                                                                                                

with  open("demo1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("welcome to python")

with open("demo2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("new world")

os.chdir(olddir) # return to original dir
```